# Working with file system from vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have a folder with 10 excel files + 1 file with macro. I open only macro. How can I get the list of all other files in folder where situated macro file (with vba) and how can I open and close them one by one?

Comment: you should examine the examples of excel-help to the topics of filesystemobject. this is a bigger task, you might want to look into this code too: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/GetFileName.aspx

Comment: Read up on DIR function.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you on the right track. These macros will loop through folder and open or close all files in the folder.

```
    Sub LoopThroughFilesAndOpen()
        Dim strFile As String
        Dim strPath As String
        Dim colFiles As New Collection
        Dim i As Integer

        strPath = "put your directory here"
        strFile = Dir(strPath)

        While strFile <> ""
            colFiles.Add strFile
            strFile = Dir
        Wend

        'List filenames in Column A of the active sheet
        If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To colFiles.Count
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = colFiles(i)
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=strPath & colFiles(i)
            Next i
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub LoopThroughFilesAndClose()
        Dim strFile As String
        Dim strPath As String
        Dim colFiles As New Collection
        Dim i As Integer

        strPath = "put your directory here"
        strFile = Dir(strPath)

        While strFile <> ""
            colFiles.Add strFile
            strFile = Dir
        Wend

        'List filenames in Column A of the active sheet
        If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To colFiles.Count
                ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = colFiles(i)
                'Workbooks.Close Filename:=strPath & colFiles(i)
                Workbooks(colFiles(i)).Close SaveChanges:=False
            Next i
        End If

    End Sub
```

Good Luck. - just put in the directy you want e.g. - "C:\myfolder\"

EDIT/ADDITION:

If you want the macros to automatically use the directy of the active workbook(the one that your running the macro from) then you can just use these versions of the above macros:

```
Sub LoopThroughFilesAndOpen()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer

    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath)

    While strFile <> ""
        colFiles.Add strFile
        strFile = Dir
    Wend

    'List filenames in Column A of the active sheet
    If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To colFiles.Count
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = colFiles(i)
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=strPath & colFiles(i)
        Next i
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoopThroughFilesAndClose()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim i As Integer

    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
    strFile = Dir(strPath)

    While strFile <> ""
        colFiles.Add strFile
        strFile = Dir
    Wend

    'List filenames in Column A of the active sheet
    If colFiles.Count > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To colFiles.Count
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = colFiles(i)
            'Workbooks.Close Filename:=strPath & colFiles(i)
            Workbooks(colFiles(i)).Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next i
    End If

End Sub
```

Which changes this line:

```
    strPath = "put your directory here"
```

To:

```
    strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\"
```

Note:

These two macros were taken and modified from:
http://www.vadriano.com/excel-vb/2007/04/21/how-to-loop-through-files-in-a-folder/

Comment: They will also put the names of each file in the active workbook/worksheet cells - you can just delete that code if you don't want that. It happens from this code: ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = colFiles(i)      -Good Luck

Comment: Nice answer.  I forgot that Dir loops this way.  One thing that you indicated, but is worth emphasizing, is that strPath must end with a "\", or better yet, `Application.PathSeparator`.

Comment: Yea, I was googling "how to get the string directory of the active workbook".