# send keys statement in excel

Tags: excel, sendkeys

[image]

I wonder If there is possibility via VBA {send keys} and coordinates to click open.
I looked for the answer FileDialogBox but, that was for selecting with mouse, then the vba saves the file path you have clicked. But what I want is to automatically select the file and click open.
It is necessary when I through macro replace paths of files inside formulas. the pop window opens up and screenupdating false event enable false does not help

Comment: You need to provide more context regarding what is contained within the formula of your cell. I think it’s very much possible. Can you provide a proper example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alt-O would open the selected folder or file, but the VBA simply won't execute while that dialog box is open. It would be better for you to rework your approach so that you are working with the file(s) directly without having to invoke the FileDialogBox.

Start here: [StackOverflow post to get you started on Excel VBA file manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566185/working-with-file-system-from-vba)